# Flash over flash - problem

Tags: html, css, flash

I have flash like a background on my page and all content on page is in the html tags witch is over that flash, and that works very nice. A cover div for that flash have a fixed position (position:fixed;) in style, that is important for scrolling feature. 
My problem is in following when I try to include  additional page, in iframe on the center of current page, and that new page containing some flash object, that object is not not visible in iframe, its here but its above the fixed flash object, if I remove (position:fixed;) from style, it is visible, but my scrolling feature not work as before. What css style could solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
```

to the `<object>` tag of the flash element you can't see? That may help.

Comment: also wmode="opaque" to the <embed> as an attribute

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing HTML 5 scrolling is not supported for Iframe
as stated before use object the object tag, and set paramaters.

```
    <object id="FlashID" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="1000" height="600"><param name="movie" value="mainswf/f_cbt.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <param name="swfversion" value="11.0.0.0" />
    <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
    <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
```